# Plotting Time series Problem with straight lines between the graph

Tags: r, plot

just in plotting there is a straight lines in the graphs. There is no complexity in codes. Maybe something wrong with my data?

[my plot with lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgV1K.jpg)
plotting  y axis= standard deviation data, x axis= date 20XX-20xx 10 year weekly observations.

```
info3<-c(date,VSP)

Date             VSP
02/01/2009  44.29181327
09/01/2009  30.12343114
16/01/2009  37.34662377
23/01/2009  45.42791909
30/01/2009  41.15014822
...              ...

Y2=info3[,-1]
dinfo3<-as.Date(as.character(info3$Date),"%d/%m/%Y")
plot(dinfo3,Y2$VSP,type="l",col="black",lwd=1)
```

I expect graphs without these lines

Answer (score 0):

Is the result the same when you plot only the VSP? Without the dates.

`VSP=runif(100)
plot(VSP, type="l", col="black", lwd=1)`